# Check All substring is present in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I want to get True if all X,Y,Z and A are in sentence. The below code works if any of them is there but I want "TRUE" if all are there else False.

```
df['D'] = (df['CT'].str.contains("X|Y|Z|A", case = False))
```

For context:

I am doing text analysis where I have a column and each row contains some text. I want to something where I can use "AND" and "OR" operator.

For example: If sentence is "I am facing issue with my internet speed". In this case I want to see if these 3 words are there Issue, internet and speed. On basis of these 3 words I will put it under "internet speed issue" bucket.

Comment: Do X, Y, Z, and A appear in a standard order in all of the strings?

Comment: How many substrings do you have?

Comment: To give more details - I am doing text analysis where i have a column and each row contains some text. I want to something where i can use "AND" and "OR" operator.         For Example- If sentence is "I am facing issue with my internet speed". In this case i want to see if these 3 words are there Issue, internet and speed . On basis of these 3 words i will put it under "internet speed issue" bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Y` always follows `X` in each string, then you change your regex to `"X.*Y"`. Adding `Z` and `A` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks i used ".+" along with //b"required word"//b and it works fine.

Comment: @DarshanC Please accept an answer that solved your problem. If there are more than one, you can upvote them.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this (?):

```py
def check_all_in(s: str, chars: str, sep='|'):
    for c in chars.split(sep):
        if c not in s:
            return False
    return True
```

Test run:

```py
teststring1 = 'A cow jumped over the moon.'
teststring2 = "A Yellow cow that I thought was a Zebra just ate my sister's Xylophone."

testchars = 'X|Y|Z|A'

print(check_all_in(teststring1, testchars))
print(check_all_in(teststring2, testchars))
```

Comment: OP is using pandas, this answer is not very helpful

Comment: i don't see pandas tagged anywhere though o.o

Comment: it's quite obvious from the code. `df['CT'].str.contains` is clearly `pandas`

Comment: Well, it's not obvious to me.

Comment: well, now it is

Comment: if you say so..

Answer (score -1):

Might look a bit convoluted but I'd use `Series.map` with `all`:

```
import pandas as pd

TRUE_VALUES = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']

df = pd.DataFrame({'CT': ['xa', 'zf', 'c', 'XyZa']})
df['D'] = df['CT'].map(lambda val: all(true_val in val.lower()
                                       for true_val in TRUE_VALUES))
print(df)
```

outputs

```
     CT      D
0    xa  False
1    zf  False
2     c  False
3  XyZa   True
```